# Document library, hide all documents by default

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a document library and I want to give access to client. I want to hide all documents by default including published documents except the few I share with them.
If I upload new document it should not be visible to them by default until I share with them.

I have given read access to client but they can see all documents by default and every time I upload a new document I have to manually control the permissions.

Comment: How have you given read access to the client? Did you add the client in Visitors group?

Comment: yes client is added to visitors group that is why they can see all documents.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is added in a group having Read access and the library permissions are inheriting from the parent, then user can see all the documents. In order to restrict user to see only the documents shared with him/her, then the library permissions need to be broken and the Read access group needs to be removed from it. 
***Go to Document Library settings -> Permissions for this document library -> Stop Inheriting Permissions***. Now remove the Read Access group.
Going forward, users will now be able to see only those documents which have been shared with them.

**UPDATE**
If it is a Publishing site, you need to deactivate feature "*Limited-access user permission lockdown mode*"

Comment: thank you, worked and answered my question, Is there any way to identify what documents are shared to a specif user? I am asking if I want to completely revoke access to all shared documents to my client.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. You can mark this as an answer and open a new question with full details.

Comment: I have posted another question, please look http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132005/sharepoint-2013-document-library-permissions-to-upload-and-view-shared-document

Answer (score 1):

Remove *'Everyone except external users'* from the *'Team Site Members*' group and Give User a *'Read'* Permission.

It will allow users to only see *Approved* documents & their own *Draft* documents.

Comment: I want to hide approved documents as well.

Comment: Then, Create any Group. Assign it permission what you want. Add users to group whom you want to give permission.Then, Grant this group Permission on document library.

Comment: but the read permission gives read rights on all documents. "I have tried to explain here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132005/sharepoint-2013-document-library-permissions-to-upload-and-view-shared-document