# SharePoint 2013 document library, permissions to upload and view shared document only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2013 document library I want to give access to client where they can upload and view their uploaded document and can see all documents shared with them.

I have managed to show all document shared with them only by deactivating a feature but now they can't upload any document, If I create a permission set to allow them to upload documents, they will see all other documents as well which are not shared with them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1) Modify the default view to only show documents that were created by/modified by [Me].

2) Add a new web page to the library and gave exclusive rights to access that to a certain set of users.

3) Restricted all users from creating a view with the help of creating special permission level where user only had access to upload or delete a document but not creating/updating/deleting lists/views. Also disabled private view creation.

Comment: I can't put modified by me condition, I want to show all documents to my team members and only shared documents to my client.